# How to retrieve link from last to first in PHP web service

Tags: php, web-services

From below PHP web services code I am able to get the link from first to last which is saved on server database.....
Now I want to get the saved link from last to first.....

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("XX.XX.XX.X:XXXX","root","root","db_");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM images");

$images = array(); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) { 
while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
$images[] = $post; 
} 
} 

header('Content-type: application/json'); 
echo json_encode(array('images'=>$images));

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The output ob above code is:
{"images":[{"image":"http://demo.in/vk/vehicles/v_1.jpg"},{"image":"http://demo.in/vk/vehicles/v_2.jpg"},{"image":"http://demo.in/vk/vehicles/v_3.jpg"},{"image":"http://demo.in/vk/vehicles/v_4.jpg"}]}

but I want It to be come like this:
{"images":[{"image":"http://demo.in/vk/vehicles/v_4.jpg"},{"image":"http://demo.in/vk/vehicles/v_3.jpg"},{"image":"http://demo.in/vk/vehicles/v_2.jpg"},{"image":"http://demo.in/vk/vehicles/v_1.jpg"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY DESC");
```

Comment: PHP Warning:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\xyz.in\demo.in\vk\vehicle.php on line 11

Comment: where I put if($result)... i m new to PHP... thnx

Comment: Change this if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) { to if($result) {

Comment: it gives only --  {"images":[]}

Comment: In sqlite you got to add $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY DESC", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT) refer to this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57624/discussion-between-zeus-and-user3431980).